# Phonegap + Facebook plugin: Ready Xcodeproj Package for iOs

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, cordova

After many and many attempts I can't get the Phonegap + [phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect) build in xCode, following the tutorial in the Facebook plugin git-hub page.

I've tried at least 6 variants and never succeeded. The latest errors I get, after a bunch related to **JSON.h** that now seem resolved after randomly messing up with project files are:

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

and

```
error: unable to open executable '/Users/franz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test_proj-fdqyszrbbbtzgtfwifiusivwzfmd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test Proj.app/Test Proj'
```

As I see, I'm in good company with several other developers around the globe.

Is there any kind soul willing to make publicly available an empty phonegap + Facebook xcodeproj using latest version of them?

---

**EDIT**

---

Since things still aren't working for me, I will keep this post up-to-date during the attempts to make it work.

**First tip:**

At step 17 from the phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect [read me](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect) you are told to remove the json folder.

> 17 from the readme: 'From your Plugins/FBConnect folder, remove the JSON folder (remove reference only)'

In short: **don't do it** if you want to build your app.
This is a [2 months old issue](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/issues/22) that has yet to be fixed.

---

**EDIT 2**

---

You can find the ready xcodeproj in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make everyone's life more simple, I decided to share a ready-to-use phonegap + Facebook plugin xcodeproj.

Download and use, very simple instructions on the link below.

[Download Phonegap + Facebook Plugin Xcodeproj](http://frario.it/?p=21)

Let me know.